# Trace call c++ Linux

Tags: linux, makefile

Портирую проект встал вопрос как выполнить trace call если у меня есть доступ к исходному коду и к Makefile (к gnuMake).

Нужно trace call по типу.

1. int main()
2. void foo1()
3. void foo2()
4. И так далее по стеку вызовов ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В gcc есть опция -finstrument-functions, которая позволяет вызывать коллбак на вызове каждой функции.

Годный пример: https://github.com/elcritch/etrace

```
main 
|   Crumble_make_apple_crumble 
|   |   Crumble_buy_stuff 
|   |   |   Crumble_buy 
|   |   |   Crumble_buy (total: 5 times) 
|   |   Crumble_prepare_apples 
|   |   |   Crumble_skin_and_dice 
|   |   Crumble_mix 
|   |   Crumble_finalize 
|   |   |   Crumble_put 
|   |   |   Crumble_put (total: 2 times) 
|   |   Crumble_cook 
|   |   |   Crumble_put 
|   |   |   Crumble_bake
```

Comment: Кажется это то что я искал спасибо !

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <execinfo.h>
int backtrace(void **buffer, int size);

char **backtrace_symbols(void *const *buffer, int size);

void backtrace_symbols_fd(void *const *buffer, int size, int fd);
```

**DESCRIPTION**

backtrace() returns a backtrace for the calling program, in the array pointed to by buffer. A backtrace is the series of currently active function calls for the program.

Answer (score 1):

Помимо `backtrace*` вы можете написать свою обёртку, которая добавляла бы произвольную информацию, позволяла бы форматировать и фильтровать её по-своему, и могла бы использовать свои логгеры. Вот пример для `C++`: [статья с исходниками](https://habrahabr.ru/post/302170/). Совместимость с `C` делается аналогично, хоть и с небольшими отличиями. Свои исходники тут приводить не буду, но могу сказать, что там немало макросов с переменным количеством аргументов, и одна проблема так и не решена. Выглядит всё как-то так:

```
static f_start( int, ab_sum, (int a, int b) )

    st_dump(NULL, NULL, " ", 2 );
    _return( a + b);
}

_main()

    int rc = ab_sum( 1, -1 );
    _return( rc );
}
```

Что в режиме отладки превращается в:

```
static int ab_sum( int a, int b ) 
{
    /* какая-то магия для сохранения информации */
    /* вывод трейса */
    return a + b;
}

int main( int argv, char **argv ) 
{
    /* инициализация трейса */
    /* какая-то магия для сохранения информации */
    int rc = ab_sum( 1, -1 );
    return rc;
}
```

При компиляции с `NDEBUG` все эти макросы раскрываются в "пустышки" и код не перегружается лишним.

В общем, всё это можно рассматривать как отправную точку, если возможностей стандартных библиотек не хватает, или нужно писать кроссплатформенный код.